# rsync between two local directories

Tags: linux, rsync, file-transfer

I am trying to do `rsync` between two directories I have in two filesystems connected to the same computer. I want to do it without deleting the extra files in `b`. I though a simple `rsync -a a/dir b/dir` would work, but it doesn't seem to. This is on a Linux system with `rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30`:

```
$ mkdir -p a/test
$ mkdir -p b/test
$ touch a/test/file1
$ touch a/test/file2
$ touch b/test/file3
$ tree a/test b/test
a/test
├── file1
└── file2
b/test
└── file3

0 directories, 3 files
$ rsync -a a/test/ b/
$ tree a/test b/test
a/test
├── file1
└── file2
b/test
└── file3

0 directories, 3 files
```

The same command *does* work when I use it on a different Linux system with a slightly newer version of rsync (`rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30`).
Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: looking at your posting "rsync -a a/test b/test" appears to do simply nothing at all, is that right? Is this a cut&paste error? I don't know the 'tree' cmd but at least both 'tree's show the same result.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seems like the problem is with the slash at the end of the SRC dir:

```
rsync -a a/test/ b/
```

vs

```
rsync -a a/test  b/
```